# How can I navigate to Sign in page if the user is not login?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to navigate to the Signin page if the user is not login. But if the user is login then it will automatically navigate to home page, but I am not able to navigate to Sign in page when user is not login. I am pasting the code below. Kindly help me if you can.

Here is my App.js code

```
import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import "./App.css";
    import { Home } from "./containers/Home";
    import { Signin } from "./containers/Signin";
    import { Signup } from "./containers/Signup";
    import PrivateRoute from "./components/HOC/PrivateRoute";

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Private route code is below

```
import React from "react";
    import { Route , Navigate } from "react-router-dom";


    const PrivateRoute = ({element:Component , ...rest})=>{
    
        return <Route {...rest} element={(props)=>{
            const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(token){
                return <Component {...props} />
            }else{
                return <Navigate to={'/signin'}/>
            }

        }} />
    }

    export default PrivateRoute;`
```

I have tried many things but they didn't work. Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

You should add `exact` to your path '/' else any path starting by '/' will be routed to your `Home` component:

`<PrivateRoute path="/" exact element={<Home />} />`

Comment: already tried, but didn't work